# Using function before declaration in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I tried writing a function but it says it is not defined, so I tried using it after declaring it, and it worked.
I program in C and there I just put function prototype and it's all good.
Is there any nice way to do this in python as well? or do I really need to think about the order that I am writing the function?
cause it sounds pretty stupid if you have a huge code with 100 functions that uses each other what do you do?

Comment: Put the functions into modules that you import

Comment: In the same file? Not nice and neatly like you can with prototypes in C. Functions should be defined before usage.